# Makefile with prerequisites in subfolder

Tags: makefile

Similar questions have been asked already, but I do not understand their answers.

About matching, `make`'s documentation says

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does
>   not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name
>   before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. [...] The
>   directories are ignored only for the purpose of finding an implicit
>   rule to use, not in the application of that rule.

Consider the following example: my makefile is

```
%.out: input/%.in
    echo $<
```

and I perform the following steps:

```
mkdir hello
mkdir -p input/hello
touch input/hello/world.in
make hello/world.out
```

This results in make not finding any rule how to build its target. But actually, I do not understand how the documentation explains this behavior, although it seems that the community agrees on that being the documented behavior. Also, I do not know how to circumvent this; resorting to fixed directory names unfortunately is no (easy to implement) option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does
>   not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name
>   before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix.

Make is trying to build the file `hello/world.out`, and looks for a matching rule. In this rule, the target pattern (`%.out`) does not contain a slash, so Make removes the directory name from the file name (leaving `world.out`) before comparing it to the target, `%.out`. It matches!

> After the comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the
>   directory names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to
>   the prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule’s
>   prerequisite patterns and the file name.

So the stem is `world`, and Make first constructs the prerequisite name according to the pattern (`input/world.in`) and then adds the directory name it removed earlier (`hello/`), so the rule requires the prerequisite `hello/input/world.in`, which does not exist (and cannot be built).

One solution is to use [the `vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search):

```
vpath %.in input

%.out: %.in
    echo $<
```

Now Make knows to search for `hello/world.in` in `input/`.